# Yslow doesnt recognize my gzip

Tags: gzip, yslow

my site is all happily Gzipped according to:

http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

However when I run it through Yslow I get a F for Gzip and it lists all of my scripts as components that are not gzipped.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look in the headers in Firebug and check that the browser is sending

```
Accept-Encoding     gzip,deflate
```

in the request header and that

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

is being sent by the server in the response header (indicating that gzipping has been applied).

Comment: I think that it's the `Content-Encoding: gzip` that determine if the content is received compressed. `Accept-Encodnig: gzip,deflate` relate to whether the browser accept `gzip` content, and it's set even if the content received isn't compressed with `gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the method in the linked pages to gzip your site, it won't have any effect on the scripts as they are not run through PHP. You'll need to either:

1) configure your webserver of choice (apache2 uses mod_deflate)

2) serve your .js files through php:

```
<?php ob_start('ob_gzhandler'); echo file_get_contents('whatever.js'); ?>
```